# How can I make it so no one can put my iWeb site in an iframe?

Tags: html, iframe, breakout, iweb

If anyone knows, I would like to make it so no one can put my iWeb site in an iframe? How do I make my pages automatically break out of iframes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14244217/16959) applies to this question as well:

This code will work if it is placed in the HTML that is referenced inside an `iframe`.  The way it works is it looks at `top` (the page you requested that includes an `iframe`) and `self` the page inside the `iframe`.  If there are different then it changes the top.location to match the URL of the `iframe`.

Here is some ASCII to help understand this

```
|----[OuterPage.html]------|
|                          |
|    |--[InnerPage.html]-| |
|    |                   | |
|    | top !== self      | |
|    |                   | |
|    |-------------------| |
|                          |
| top === self             |
|                          |
|--------------------------|
```

If you request InnerPage.html by itself (not in an iframe) then `top === self` will evaluate to true, however if you request the same page inside an iframe then the same condition will evaluate as false.

Answer (score 1):

There is also a http header `X-Frame-Origin` as specified [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/X-Frame-Options), that you can put into the server response, which will block the browser from rendering the iframe at all, if set to `SAMEORIGIN`.

However it's a browser dependant solution (as in the browser will have to support the header to respect its value), but nicer than JS trickery IMO.

Comment: What if you combine both solutions - is there any benefit to using both over using just the javascript solution?

Comment: No reason you couldn't do both, the JS would fire for any browsers that don't respect header. It's still not 100% successful though (Someone could be on an unsupporting browser, with JS disabled), but that's such an edge-case I would say it's not really worth worrying about.