# Want to understand iframe breakout code

Tags: javascript, iframe, breakout

With this script code (below) placed in between the head tags, I am told that this will not allow the page to load in an iframe.

If this is correct, is there anything that needs to be replaced with my custom URL or similar in this code (e.g., `top.location` should be `top.myurl`)?

Or do you leave it as it is, and just paste it in the head of the page? I'm trying to understand how this works.

```
if (top.location!= self.location) {
  top.location = self.location.href
}
```

Comment: Did [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14244217/16959) help?

Comment: You should improve your "acceptance rating" by marking correct answers.

Comment: I Can't until I have a 15 reputation, I only have 4.

Comment: I wasn't aware of that rule, sorry

Answer (score 0):

This code will work if it is placed in the HTML that is referenced inside an `iframe`.  The way it works is it looks at `top` (the page you requested that includes an `iframe`) and `self` the page inside the `iframe`.  If there are different then it changes the top.location to match the URL of the `iframe`.

Here is some ASCII to help understand this

```
|----[OuterPage.html]------|
|                          |
|    |--[InnerPage.html]-| |
|    |                   | |
|    | top !== self      | |
|    |                   | |
|    |-------------------| |
|                          |
| top === self             |
|                          |
|--------------------------|
```

If you request InnerPage.html by itself (not in an iframe) then `top === self` will evaluate to true, however if you request the same page inside an iframe then the same condition will evaluate as false.